# SSIS GUIDs as automaticly generated Id's from the XML source component

Tags: ssis

Is it possible to setup the XML Source component so that it generates GUID, instead of the default int, values for the automatically generated _id column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve my problems was to write a custom component. No other alternatives where available.

Answer (score 0):

I would send each output from the XML Source to a SQL table (using an OLE DB Destination), and add a GUID column to each table.

Actually I would forget about GUIDs because they are painful in general and with SSIS in particular - it essentially does not provide any support for GUIDs.

Comment: the problem is with the XML Source and multiple child elements which are now linked by a generated column (_id) which is also used for linking the elements together. The problem is that the generated id is unique per XML file but not if i want to process multiple files in which case i can get duplicated ids (which aren't nicely sequential anyways). Using a GUID as an identifier makes it (nearly) always unique.

Comment: Nearly.  I would use variable holding the XML file name to generate a new column in a Derived Column transformation in each Data Flow, then add that to each output table and include it in the Primary Key.